# can we create a task in outlook using EWS API in other email account

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Can i create outlook task using my exchange credential in different email account?
i am using my exchange server credential to create task in outlook. all the task are created under my outlook account.i need to create the task in different account (same exchange server) using my credential.

Answer (score 1):

Try Impersonation. Impersonation enables a caller to impersonate a given account so that a caller can perform operations by using the permissions that are associated with the impersonated account instead of the permissions that are associated with the caller's account.
for more detail see the following link-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx